# SearchBar unfocus automatically after using TextChanged event in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, searchbar

I have a simple **search-bar** component and its **TextChanged** event

```
   <SearchBar x:Name="SearchBar" Placeholder="Search words..."
                                       CancelButtonColor="Black"
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       PlaceholderColor="Black"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                       FontSize="Medium"
                               
                                       TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged"
                                      />
```

In `SearchBar_TextChanged()` method I try to find data by text and assign it to the item source. Everything works fine but the problem is that the search-bar gets unfocused after the filter.

```
  private async void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
                words.ItemsSource = await wordRepository.GetAllAsync();
            else
                words.ItemsSource = await wordRepository.Find(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to let your searchbar focus manually.

```
 private async void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue)){
            words.ItemsSource = await wordRepository.GetAllAsync();
        }else{
            words.ItemsSource = await wordRepository.Find(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()));
        }
        SearchBar.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue in the absence of data acquisition and filtering,the search bar still focus when i handle the SearchBar_TextChanged mryhod.

Answer (score 0):

the issue seems to occure when you are using the SearchBar in a Collection\ListView's Header, so just move to outside of it.